# Yahoo orders export XML -- web services?

Tags: php, xml, yahoo-api

Sorry if this is too remedial or repetitive in any way but I need some advice. I'm a PHP guy and I've been asked to create a container-type app to capture our yahoo! store orders data, which is sent as xml using this DTD:

http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/store/order/retrieve/retrieve-20.html

The Y! Store wants us to specify a URL on our web server to send the XML data to, and here is their example:

http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/vw/OrderList.xml

But am I missing something here? I've worked with simplexml_load_file() to parse XML files. But what do I need to build a web service here? How do I GET the data? I'm not even sure if Y! is sending it as a POST or how to validate it.

Do I need additional documentation on their end? If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,
-Bob

Comment: You need additional documentation. The XML could be sent as part of a SOAP request, or as plain XML request (i.e. with a Content-Type of application/xml), or as a field in some application/x-www-form-urlencoded data, it might be POSTed or PUT, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm never one to answer my own questions but I just thought I'd leave this for someone else some day down the road, considering Y! isn't the best with documentation on this.

The orders export from Y! Store is straight XML, not SOAP. If sent to an Apache server, you're in luck -- it's a simple $_POST. So all you need is:

$variable = file_get_contents("php://input");

In my case, however, things were complicated with IIS so I had to add HTTP verb, open up the folder permissions, etc.

-Good coding, all

Answer (score -1):

Being a PHP guy have nothing to do with understanding webserves. Webservices isn't really have a POST or GET, it sending an envelope (XML), and expecting a response, also in XML.

You need to learn how to use SoapClient on PHP, here is a good place to start:
http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Validation is something you do before sending the soap request, and validation of what is being sent back from Y! is also done by you. Hope this help you get started.

Comment: Webservers very much **do** use POST and GET, it is just that ones that accept POST requests often expect the data to use a format other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Why would SoapClient be useful? Do you have any documentation to say that Yahoo! will be using SOAP? If so, why would a SOAP **client** library be useful (given that the question states Yahoo! want a URL to send the data **to**, which would require a *server*)?

Comment: @Quentin, if it quacks like a duck and looks like a duck, I assumed it was a duck, such as if it expects XML and returns XML, and it is a web service. I assumed it was a Soap Service, If you don't like my suggest / assumption of webservice, offer another solution.